# Send Custom message in Django PermissionDenied

Tags: python, django, view, decorator, permission-denied

I am using django's `PermissionDenied` to render `403.html` whenever the user is not allowed to access any page.

There are whole lot of pages, of different type, for example, `Product page`, `User Page`, `User Contact information`, `Owner Information`.

I would like to add the custom message with `PermissionDenied`, that would tell the user exactly why he can not view this page. I would like to add the following dynamic message to the `403.html`.

```
You have are trying to `View a Product (id:3094384)` while having a `Trail` account. You are not authorized to view this product.
```

And

```
 You have are trying to `View a Customer (id:48)` which is Private. You are not authorized to view this User.
```

and so on.

### here is my code

```
elif role.id == Project.ROLE_SALES and not project.sales_person_id == user_id:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

### html

```
<body class="error-page">

<!--  content -->
<section>
    <div class="error403">
        <h1>403</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="description">Oops! Request forbidden...</p>

    <p>Sorry, it appears the page you were looking for is forbidden and not accessible. If the problem persists, please
        contact web Administrator.</p>


# HERE I WANT TO SHOW DYNAMIC MESSAGE. 



    <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}" class="btn btn-danger403 btn-primary btn-large" >
        Go Back </a>
{{ except }}
</section>



<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
</body>
```

### Possibility

```
raise PermissionDenied("Custom message")
```

### Or

Pass a context to `PermissionDenied`?

Suggestions.

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view

Comment: Yes, i have. i am able to render 403.html, but thats static,same for all premissiondenied responses. I want to send some params (context) on the type of request and show different messages.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue @Clayton?

Comment: yes. i was able to @rka

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This answer is probably arriving very late for you. But here it is.
You can use this in your Django code:

```
raise PermissionDenied("Custom message")
```

And then display the custom message using below snippet in the 403.html template:

```html
{% if exception %}
  <p>{{ exception }}</p>
{% else %}
  <p>Static generic message</p>
{% endif %}
```

The message string passed to 'PermissionDenied' is available in template context as explained in Django documentation -
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#http-forbidden-view

Comment: I am facing a similar dilemma. Could you check my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167348/how-to-display-permission-denied-message-in-custom-403-html-page-in-django)?

Comment: You can find the default template for 403 errors here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/defaults.py

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue and resolved it using the Django messages framework to pass a custom message to the template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/

My specific example:

```
from django.contrib import messages
...
messages.error(request, 'The submission deadline has passed.')
raise PermissionDenied
```

The messages can then be output in the template as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
class SomeException(Exception):
    message = 'An error occurred.'

    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.message)

#usage
 raise SomeException("Hello, you have an exception here")
```

Another way of sending a message to template is like:

```
if not request.user.is_staff: #or your condition
   context['flash_message']= "permission error occurred"
   retrun render_to_response('template.html', context)

# template
<!-- I am using bootstrap here -->
<div class="alert alert-{{ flash_message_type }} flash_message hide">
    {{ flash_message | safe }}
</div>

<script>
...
if($.trim($(".flash_message").html()) != ''){
        $(".flash_message").slideDown();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".flash_message").slideUp();
        }, 5000);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. I want to redirect user to the new page that only shows error. PremissionDenied always shows one page 403.html but i want to show custom message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using class based views (CBV), or anything that extends the `AccessMixin`, either set the `permission_denied_message` attribute, or override the `get_permission_denied_message` method.

Example:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyView(ListView):
    permission_denied_message = 'Hooo!'

    def get_permission_denied_message(self):
        perms = self.get_permission_required()
        if settings.DEBUG:
            for perm in perms:
                if not self.request.user.has_perm(perm):
                    return 'Permission denied: ' + str(perm)
        return ''
```

and then, in your template:

```
{% if exception and debug %}
    <h3 class="font-bold">{{ exception }}</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I render the permission denied only in the development, thus, `DEBUG` is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.

In [django 1.9 we have this built in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.permission_denied). In earliest django version we can use [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), so the next step is just reuse whole default `permission_denied` handler to add our exception.

```
# urls.py
...
handler403 = 'project.views.errors.permission_denied'
...

# views/errors.py
import sys

from django import http
from django.template import Context, TemplateDoesNotExist, loader
from django.views.decorators.csrf import requires_csrf_token


@requires_csrf_token
def permission_denied(request, template_name='403.html'):
    _, value, _ = sys.exc_info()

    try:
        template = loader.get_template(template_name)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>', content_type='text/html')
    return http.HttpResponseForbidden(
        template.render(request=request, context={'exception': force_text(value)})
    )

# templates/403.html
...
{{ exception }}
...
```