# How to display "permission_denied_message" in custom 403.html page in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, exception, permission-denied, user-permissions

How do we correctly display **exception message** in custom **403 error** in Django?

In my signup view I am using:

```
class SignUpView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'error_403'
    # ....
    # ...
    permission_denied_message = 'You are not allowed this transaction!! Ha Ha!!'
#    raise PermissionDenied() # ('permission_denied_message')
    raise_exception = True
```

Now how do I display the message ("`permission_denied_message`"?) in my custom *403.html*?

This is my function to render the error page:

```
def error_403(request, exception):
    data = {}
    add_user = 'add_user'
    data = {'perm': add_user}
    return render(request, '403.html', data)
```

I have been through a lot of matter on the subject (including those on SO) but could not succeed in displaying the error message (except the static message that I have put in my "*403.html*"). I have used `{{ exception}}` in the template but nothing gets displayed (execpt the static message that I already have).

**1. How do I display the `permission_denied_message` in custom 403 page?**

**2. Presently I am manually updating some raw data in dict `data{}` in function `error_403`, which gets rendered on the 403 error page. What is the correct usage of the dict?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use django messages framework to perform this. This allows you to add custom messages you want to send to the template.
You need to import it from django.contrib. Here is the code to send an error message to the template.

```
from django.contrib import messages
# In your function you do this


def error_403(request, exception):
    error_message = messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "permission denied")
    errors = {'errors': error_message}
    return render(request, '403.html', errors)
```

In your template you can check if there are error messages and then display them

```
<h1> {{errors}} </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, and I haven't been able to find any nice simple and straighforward way.

I digged down into the official django documentation and inside the Django code.

Here is the simple answer:

1/ you define your view as simple as possible, adding only the mixins:

```
class SignUpView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'can_xxx'
    permission_denied_message = 'You are not allowed this transaction!! Ha Ha!!'
```

2/ you create in your app template folder the file `my_app/template/403.html` as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Permission Denied</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>403 - Permission Denied</h1>
    <p>{{ exception }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and everything is working magically !